# Format numbers under 100 with a 0 in front

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gis

I've written a program that will print out adjacent NTS mapsheets but I want to format the numbers under 100 with a 0 in front of them.

ex. user enters 094m the output now is : "The adjacent map sheets are 104P 94N 95D 94L"

I want them to be: The adjacent map sheets are 104P 094N 095D 094L

These are the initial variables for the numbers:

```
    int westBlockNumber = Integer.parseInt(blockNumberAsString);
    int eastBlockNumber =  Integer.parseInt(blockNumberAsString);
    int northBlockNumber =Integer.parseInt(blockNumberAsString);
    int southBlockNumber =  Integer.parseInt(blockNumberAsString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.format`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to introduce leading zeros:

```
String threeDigitsNumber = String.format("%03d", westBlockNumber);
```

With `3` being the number of digits, and `%0` the number of leading zeros in front of a number.